# Finding all pythagorean triplets between 100 to 1000

Tags: c++, c++11, cmath, pythagorean, triplet

I wrote a program to find pythagorean triplets between 100 to 1000.
Here goes the code for the same.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

bool checkWhetherInteger(int x, int y);
int getInteger(int x, int y);

int main() 
{
    cout << "This program is to print all pythagorean triplets from 100 to 1000. \n";

    int x=100;
    int y=100;

    for(; x<=1000; x++)
    {
        for (; y<=1000; y++)
        {
            if (checkWhetherInteger(x,y))
            {
                cout << "Triplet : " << x << "  " << y << "  " << getInteger(x,y) << "\n";
            }
        }
        y=100;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool checkWhetherInteger(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i=141; i<=1415; i++)
    {
        if(hypot(x,y) == i )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int getInteger(int x, int y)
{
    return static_cast<int>(hypot(x,y));

}
```

There are two problems I am facing right now.

1. The main problem is it executes slowly. While it gave me all the triplets it took about  553.7 seconds to execute. So is there any algorithm by which the thing I wanna achieve can be done in 1-2 seconds or less.
2. Due to two independent variables x and y I am getting one triplet twice. What can be done about that.

If I've done some mistake, Please bear with me. I'm a learner.

Comment: You have three nested loops running about 1000 times each. That makes the inner code run about a billion times. Might take a while! I think perhaps you could do `double h = hypot(x,y); return h == int(h);` to make it run 1000 times faster.

Comment: That worked! executed in less than 3 seconds; btw can you please tell what int() does?

Comment: Why don't you use allready calced results like a chess-programm using opening-books? You would gain results within miliseconds! ("think differnent" - Steve Jobs) ^^

Comment: @Vaibhav - The `int(h)` is converting to an `int`, using a constructor style cast. In C it would be written `(int)h`.

Comment: You have UB, as you may don't return in `checkWhetherInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to find all triples involves usage of this formula:

```
a = k(x^2 - y^2)
b = k(2xy)
c = k(x^2 + y^2)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

The standard (and one of the fastest) way to remove duplicates: use std::set<>.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

struct Triple {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

struct comp {
  inline bool operator ()(const Triple & first, const Triple & second) const {
    if (first.a != second.a) {
      return first.a < second.a;
    }
    if (first.b != second.b) {
      return first.b < second.b;
    }
    return first.c < second.c;
  }
};

int main() {
  int n = 1000;
  std::set<Triple, comp> set;
  for (int x = 2; x <= n; ++x) {
    for (int y = 1; y < x && x * x + y * y <= n; ++y) {
      int a = x * x - y * y;
      int b = 2 * x * y;
      if (a > b) {
        std::swap(a, b);
      }
      int c = x * x + y * y;
      for (int k = 1; k * c <= n; ++k) {
        if (a * k >= 100 && a * k <= n &&
            b * k >= 100 && b * k <= n &&
            c * k >= 100 && c * k <= n)
        set.insert({k * a, k * b, k * c});
      }
    }
  }
  for (const auto & triple : set) {
    std::cout << triple.a << " " << triple.b << " " << triple.c << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b270a1013657a3)